# Should I check in sites/default/files?

Tags: 8, files, installation, version-control

I installed a fresh D8 and was going for the usual setup of sending code and config to repo, and db sync (from a backup dump or sync from remote). Now when I reproduce the site given the code, config, and dump, I notice that **the site has no styles**.

Comparing the restored setup and another fresh install, I notice that **`sites/default/files` is missing in the restored setup**. This directory is ignored by default because it's supposed to house user generated files. However, a fresh install of **D8 appears to put files related to theming in that directory**.

So my questions are:

- Why is this directory ignored by `.gitignore` if theme files reside there?
- What is the proper way to do this? Should I check-in these files?
- What else should I or should not I be checking-in?

And we don't have a common remote environment as of the moment so an "rsync from remote" doesn't apply, nor does checking-in archives as we just want code in the repo.

Comment: Presumably you have CSS/JS aggregation turned on? If so just clear cache, the problem will be solved. Those files _are_ user generated (or Drupal-generated to be strictly accurate), and they shouldn't be added to git

Comment: @Clive OMG, aggregation *is* on by default :facepalm:. Thanks!

Comment: I think that the config sync directory should be also present.

Comment: @IvanJaros I've already moved it out of `sites/default/files` so that's aready fine.

Comment: cool, then it's just usual git pull & drush cr :D